# Draw even and odd parts of following signal

Tags: signal, signal-theory

[image][image]

I think my odd signal is wrong because odd signal cannot be symmetric about y axis

Comment: The numbers you encircled are not symmetric. As I think you represent the area under the graph with those numbers: double check the number between x= 1 and x=2

Comment: Can you draw the odd signal?

Comment: @Aayushpeace While we are glad to help you understand your homework and point you in the right direction, we will not do your homework for you.

Comment: I don't understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: Remove the DC component.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This should be the answer I was taking downward slope as positive my mistake